# ruby dry run No such file or directory /platform-tools/adb (Errno::ENOENT)

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

how can i fix this problem ?   when i using dryrun.   log is here.

> ➜  ~ dryrun git@github.com:cesarferreira/android-helloworld.git
>   Searching for devices...
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:211:in
>   `spawn': No such file or directory - /platform-tools/adb
>   (Errno::ENOENT)   from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:211:in`
>   popen_run'   from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open3.rb:99:in
>   `popen3'  from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dryrun-0.8.1/lib/dryrun/dryrun_utils.rb:50:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dryrun-0.8.1/lib/dryrun/dryrun_utils.rb:46:in
>   `run_adb'     from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dryrun-0.8.1/lib/dryrun.rb:108:in`pick_device'     from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dryrun-0.8.1/lib/dryrun.rb:171:in `call'    from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/dryrun-0.8.1/bin/dryrun:5:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/dryrun:23:in `load'  from
>   /Users/baidu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/dryrun:23:in`'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're receiving is dryrun not being able to recognize an adb path. The adb path needs to be set to `ANDROID_HOME`, for `dryrun` to work.

**Steps to Fix this:**

1. `echo export "ANDROID_HOME=/Users/yourName/Library/Android/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile`
2. `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. `echo $ANDROID_HOME`
4. Test `dryrun git@github.com:cesarferreira/android-helloworld.git`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/cesarferreira/dryrun#notes):

> ANDROID_HOME needs to be set with the adb path.

Open the file `~/.bash_profile` (`~/.zshenv` if you are using Zsh) or create it if it does not exist, and add the following (with your real Android SDK path):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{your_user}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your ANDROID_HOME